# How to call onResume() of a child Fragment and not onResume() of the parent Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

Suppose I have 3 `Fragment`s, `BaseFragment`, and first fragment and second fragment.

I have implemented `onResume()` of `BaseFragment` and written a code to set the width and height like -

```
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(params);

    Log.d("upisdk", "basedialogfragment onresume()");
}
```

I have a first fragment, in which I want to set the width to, for example, 90% of the total width. I have implemented `onResume()` here also -

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = (getWidth(getContext()) / 100) * 90;
    params.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(params);

    Log.d("upisdk", "onresume called on Changeddialogfragment");

}
```

And in `SecondFragment` I want to set to 80% I did this just like the above `Fragment`.

My `onResume()` is getting called twice. Once for `BaseFragment` and the other time for `FirstFragment`.

is this possible to call only first fragment onResume and not the parent one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this possible to call only first fragment onResume and not the parent one?

No, it isn't possible. This is what I get when I override `onResume()` in a Fragment and delete the line with `super.onResume();`

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.mytestapp/com.example.mytestapp.MainActivity}: android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment MyTestFragment{4037a6b #0 id=0x7f090035 fragment} did not call through to super.onResume()

[...]

> Caused by: android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment
>   MyTestFragment{4037a6b #0 id=0x7f090035 fragment} did not call
>   through to super.onResume()

But you can introduce a field `protected int percent = x;` in `BaseFragment` and let it have a different value *x* for each `Fragment`.

You can set this value in any method which gets called before `onResume()` and does not have to call through to its superclass implementation, e.g. in `onCreateView()`.

Or you introduce your own method and call it from e.g. `onCreate()`

For example for the parent class:

```
protected void setPercent(){
    percent = 100;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setPercent();
}
```

Whereas in the first `Fragment`, you write

```
@Override
protected void setPercent(){
    percent = 90;
}
```

Then the child `Fragment`s don't need to override `onResume()` and the parent class is able to set the `LayoutParams` correctly:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = (getWidth(getContext()) * percent / 100);
    params.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(params);
}
```

Comment: So, for the first fragment, I have set the percent value. i need to pass the value of the percent to the BaseFragment or where my onResume is overrided?

Comment: @Aman Verma - you can set the value for the field as part of the child Fragment's code like this: `protected int percent = 90;` This way, *percent* will have the correct value once the Fragment's constructor has finished. So in onResume(), one formula is able to cover all cases

Comment: BaseFragment and the FirstFragment are two different classes. Are you aware of that??

Comment: @Aman Verma - yup. You said FirstFragment extends from BaseFragment, didn't you?

Comment: @Aman Verma - ok, I think there is one mistake in my approach. Which can be amended by overriding any method whch gets called before onResume()... will edit my answer